# Arrange UILabels along circle

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have several UILabels which I would like to arrange in a half-circle, i.e. the left-most would be rotated 90deg counterclockwise, the middle one moved up and is not rotated, the right-most is rotated 90 clockwise.

Any ideas on the best practise to achieve this? Or is better to draw the text in the view and forget about UILabels?

Comment: An image of the desired effect would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I got your back:

http://www.platinumball.net/blog/2009/06/01/drawing-nsstrings-in-unusual-rotations/

(an easy abstraction for rotating text)

Answer (score 0):

You're right - forget about UILabels and draw the text in the view.